# Is there a way to retrieve all activities that happened to object? Getstream.io

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

Hello i'm working with getstream.io. Is it possible to fetch all activities based on object? Let's say I have 2 people that made an activity about eating a burger and 1 person who ate spaghetti. Is it possible to fetch all activities that happened to hamburger? So the outcome should be 2 activities of those people who ate it. Thank you for response